# Time optimization of counting shifts in insertion sort

Tags: python, optimization, sorting, python-3.x, insertion-sort

Is there any way of counting how many shifts would it take to count shifts while doing insertion sort?  This is a Hackerrank problem. Here's my solution, but it takes more than 16 seconds.

```
counts = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    size = int(input())
    ar = list(map(int, input().split()))
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, len(ar)):
        j = i
        while j >= 1 and ar[j] < ar[j-1]:
            ar[j], ar[j-1] = ar[j-1], ar[j]
            j -= 1
            count+=1
    counts.append(count)
for c in counts: print(c)
```

> Insertion Sort is a simple sorting technique which was covered in
>   previous challenges. Sometimes, arrays may be too large for us to wait
>   around for insertion sort to finish. Is there some other way we can
>   calculate the number of times Insertion Sort shifts each elements when
>   sorting an array?
>
> If ki is the number of elements over which ith element of the array
>   has to shift then total number of shift will be k1 + k2 + … + kN.
>
> Input: The first line contains the number of test cases T. T test
>   cases follow. The first line for each case contains N, the number of
>   elements to be sorted. The next line contains N integers
>   a[1],a[2]…,a[N].
>
> Output: Output T lines, containing the required answer for each test
>   case.

That's the problem. Is there any way I could optimize my solution?

Comment: My code did 0.04s: https://github.com/LeandroTk/Algorithm_DataStructure/blob/master/insertion_sort.py I think your code takes more than 16 seconds, because of the 3 nested loops.. (n³).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insertion sort is an O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.  There's only so much you can do to optimize it.

This is a bit of trick question.  It doesn't actually ask you to sort the arrays in question; it just asks you to count the number of shifts involved.  So, for each element to be "inserted", just count the number of preceding elements that have a larger value.

Stylistically, your program should be modularized.  Each of the *T* test cases is independent, so isolate each test case in a function.  You probably don't have to buffer the results, either — just print the result from each test case as soon as you have the answer.

Comment: you mean to remove those swaps?

Comment: Yes, that's right. [Hint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2643910/1157100)